# Debugging a C Obscure Pointer Problem, creating a dynamic array at the location of an argument

Tags: c, arrays, pointers, debugging, dynamic-memory-allocation

I am facing a weird pointer problem that I can't seem to figure out. In one function (this case `main`) I want to declare a pointer `**arr` that should ultimately become a 2D array. I then want to pass that pointer to a function (`fillArray`) where I want to generate the 2D array with `dyn2Darray` and then fill up that array with some data. Then back in `main` I want to do something with the data. Unfortunately this results in a core dump. Maybe some wise C-Master could tell me what I am doing wrong with my pointers. Also, the dimensions of the array (`r` and `c`) are determined in `fillArray` in the actual problem, so shifting around definitions would not help me. I am pretty sure that there must be a way to do this, since everything is possible with C.

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>

int **dyn2Darray(int I, int J)
{
    int **arr = malloc(sizeof(int *) * I + sizeof(int) * I * J);
    int *ptr = (int *)(arr + I);
    for (int i = 0; i < I; ++i) {
        arr[i] = (ptr + J * i);
    }
    return arr;
}

void fillArray(int ***arr, int r, int c)
{
    int count = 0,i,j;
    *arr = dyn2Darray(r, c);
    for (i = 0; i < r; i++)
        for (j = 0; j < c; j++)
            *arr[i][j] = ++count;
}

int main()
{
    int r=3, c=4;
    int **arr = NULL;
    int i,j;

    fillArray(&arr, r, c);

    for (i = 0; i < r; i++)
        for (j = 0; j < c; j++)
            printf("%d ", arr[i][j]);

    return 0;
}
```

EDIT: The solution was found by debugging with Visual Studio. My question now changed: How could I debug this with `gdb`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Debugging your code in visual studio shows that the 'for' loop in *fillArray()* function was actually assigning values to the row pointers of the 2d array, that's why the program crashed after 3 iterations(since the number of rows was 3). Of course, the solution was simple: -

```
void fillArray(int ***arr, int r, int c)
{
    int count = 0,i,j;
    *arr = dyn2Darray(r, c);
    for (i = 0; i < r; i++)
        for (j = 0; j < c; j++)
            (*arr)[i][j] = ++count;    //<------------CHANGE HERE
}
```

C can be annoying sometimes, especially due to priority problems like this.

Also, do not forget to free the allocated memory.

Comment: Oh my! Thank you very much, I did not see that coming. Of course it will be freeed, that is why I spent all of yesterday to come up with a way to make a 2D array with just one malloc call :)

Comment: Do you, or somebody else maybe know, how I could debug this on the command line with `gdb`?

Comment: @koipond
Never tried gdb, but maybe check out this tutorial [link](https://u.osu.edu/cstutorials/2018/09/28/how-to-debug-c-program-using-gdb-in-6-simple-steps/)